# Robospice и кеширование в базу данных

Tags: java, android, кэширование, robospice

Здравствуйте!

Никак не могу разобраться с `robospice`.

Задача в том, что нужно полученные данные сохранять в БД, записей должно быть достаточно много.
Как после получения данных с сервера, используя эту библиотеку, я могу сохранять/удалять/обновлять данные в БД для постоянного хранения? Или нужно еще какую то библиотеку?

Одна из задач, это чат - сообщения должны храниться в БД и быть доступны для просмотра в *оффлайн режиме*

**upd**: можно ли использовать `greenDao` с `robospice`?

Comment: `robospice` не работает напрямую с БД, вам нужно сохранять данные полученные этой библиотекой самостоятельно. Сейчас идет тестирование [взаимодействия с ORMLite](https://github.com/stephanenicolas/robospice/wiki/ORMLite-module) - если это вас устроит, можете принять участие.

Comment: @pavlofff, был бы рад какому нибудь примеру. Потому, как не понятно, как сохранять данные навсегда. Т.к. тут есть запросы, которые сохраняют на время `DurationMillis`